# How to smooth data

Tags: python, smoothing

I have a data file that I would like to smooth out. I am not sure on how to do it. I have looked at a few things and nothing really helps. here is my code as is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data1 = np.loadtxt('2_Record2308.dat')
plt.title('2_Record2308')

plt.plot(data1)
plt.show()
```

I know you can do it with the "spicy" thing but I would prefer not to use it.

Comment: Spicy? Do you mean scipy?

Comment: haha yes sorry!